# How to prevent Spark SQL + Power BI OOM

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Now I'm testing Spark SQL like an query engine for Microsoft Power BI.
What I have:

1. A huge Cassandra table with data I need to analyze.
2. An Amazon server with 8 cores and 16Gb of RAM.
3. A Spark Thrift server on this server. Version of Spark - 1.6.1
4. A Hive table mapped to a huge Cassandra table.

`create table data using org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra options (cluster 'Cluster', keyspace 'myspace', table 'data')`;

All was ok until I tried to connect Power BI to Spark. The problem is that Power BI is trying to fetch all data from huge Cassandra table. Obviously Spark Thrift Server crashes with OOM Error. In this case I cant just add RAM to Spark Thrift Server because Cassandra table with raw data is really huge. Also I cant rely on custom initial query on BI side, because every time user forget about setting this query server would crash.
The best approach I see is in automatically wrapping all queries from BI in some kind of

```
SELECT * FROM (... BI select ...) LIMIT 1000000
```

It will be okay for current use cases.
So, is it possible on the server side? How I can do it?
If not, how I can prevent Spark Thrift Server crashes? Is there a possibility to drop or cancel huge queries before getting OOM?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi @serge-harnyk. I am trying to connect spark server from Power BI, could you please help take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502460/how-to-connect-to-spark-server-from-power-bi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I find a magic configuration option that solves my problem:

spark.sql.thriftServer.incrementalCollect=true

When this option is set, Spark splits the data that is fetched by a volume-consuming query to chunks